# Vue.js For loop is not rendering content

Tags: django, vue.js, material-design-lite, vue-resource

I am building a web application using vue.js, vue-resource, vue-mdl and google material design lite.
JS compilation is performed using webpack through laravel elixir.
In this app I have to render a table row for each object from an array returned from a Rest API (Django Rest Framework). I have made the following code inside the html to render content using vue.js:

```
<tr v-for="customer in customers">
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ customer.status }}</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ customer.name }}</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ customer.company }}</td>
<tr>
```

This should render all objects in the array as a table row. I have also tried to wrap the above in a template tag like this:

```
<template v-for="customer in customers">
<tr>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ customer.status }}</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ customer.name }}</td>
    <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ customer.company }}</td>
</tr>
</template>
```

This did not change either.
I have also tried to hardcode the array inside the ready() function of the vue instance, but this did not help either.

```
window._ = require('lodash');
require('material-design-lite');
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');
var VueMdl = require('vue-mdl');
Vue.use(VueMdl.default);
const app = new Vue({
    el:'body',
    ready: function(){
        //this.getCustomerList();
        this.customers = [
            { name: "Peter", status: "true", company: "Company 1"},
            { name: "John", status: "false", company: "Company 2"}
        ]

    },
    data: {
        customers: [],
        response: null,
        messages: []
    },
    methods: {
        getCustomerList: function()
        {
            this.$http({url: '/api/customers/', method: 'GET'}).then(function(response){
                //Success
                this.customers = response.data
                console.log(response.data)
            },
            function(response){
                console.log(response)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Changing the above to this does not change either:

```
window._ = require('lodash');
require('material-design-lite');
window.Vue = require('vue');
require('vue-resource');
var VueMdl = require('vue-mdl');
Vue.use(VueMdl.default);
const app = new Vue({
    el:'body',
    ready: function(){
        //this.getCustomerList();

    },
    data: {
        customers: [
            { name: "Peter", status: "true", company: "Company 1"},
            { name: "John", status: "false", company: "Company 2"}
        ],
        response: null,
        messages: []
    },
    methods: {
        getCustomerList: function()
        {
            this.$http({url: '/api/customers/', method: 'GET'}).then(function(response){
                //Success
                this.customers = response.data
                console.log(response.data)
            },
            function(response){
                console.log(response)
            })
        }
    }
})
```

I have also tried to just make a plain html table that does not have any of the Google MDL classes applied, and this does also not give any result.
Logging `this.customers` to the console shows that it does in fact contain the data, but for reason it is not rendering. Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors in console? Is there a `<table>` tag wrapping your `<tr>` group?

Comment: Nothing in the console and of course it is wrappen in a ```<table>``` and also a ```<tbody>```.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet of your code, which works as expected. I've added in CDN references to the libraries you mentioned, but I'm not doing anything with them. I offer this as a starting point for you to see if you can find what changes will reproduce your problem here.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  ready: function() {
    //this.getCustomerList();
    this.customers = [{
      name: "Peter",
      status: "true",
      company: "Company 1"
    }, {
      name: "John",
      status: "false",
      company: "Company 2"
    }]
  },
  data: {
    customers: [],
    response: null,
    messages: []
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/0.9.3/vue-resource.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.2.0/material.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/posva/vue-mdl/develop/dist/vue-mdl.min.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">
    <button id="create-customer" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect" @click="$refs.createCustomer.open">
      Create customer
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">
    <button id="convert-reseller" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Convert to reseller
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">
    <button id="remove-customer" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Remove Customer
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col">
    <button id="change-status" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect">
      Change status
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
    <table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable" style="width:100%;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Status</th>
          <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Customer name</th>
          <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Company</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="customer in customers">
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ customer.status }}</td>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ customer.name }}</td>
          <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">{{ customer.company }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems now to be working.
Inside `app.js` I had:

```
const app = new Vue({ el: 'body' })
```

That, for some reason, conflicted with the one I was creating inside `customer_list.js`—although my methods worked fine.